# Error while running a Android activity on Genymotion Virtual device

Tags: java, android, genymotion

Here is the problem I get. I didn't even put something to run and get result. I have basic empty activity and maps activity. I try to run it on `genymotion` virtual device.

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE]
>     $ adb shell pm uninstall com.example.emrullah.placemarkermymapsappcontinue
>     Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674))
>     Error while Installing APK

Answer (score 0):

You could try **disable** Instant Run.

[image]

Comment: I tried but didnt work